# Simplest way for implementing an extremly simple Server? (C#)

Tags: c#

I'm currently writing a simple application for some friends of mine.
There is a pretty small part which contains some client-server communication. Protocolls like http are far to overloaded with unnecessary stuff I don't need.

Here is all the communication I need to implement:

```
(Request -> Response)
* {AccountID} -> {AccountBalance}
* {AccountID,newBalance} -> {AccountBalance}
* {AccountID,ItemID,Amount} -> {AccountBalance}
* {ItemID} -> {ItemValue}
```

All values are integer. AccountIDs and ItemIDs are distinguished. AccountBalances and ItemValues are always positiv.

Since the application will only be used in a private LAN security is not important.

I already tried using a httpListener for that, but it seems like it wasn't suitable for my needs.

Comment: Why didn't httpListener work for you?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out why my httpListener solution didn't work. But since WCF seems to be exactly what i need I'm very glad i asked here. As far as I understand http it was never designed to send/receive such Datagrams (unless you're willing to xml-serialize everything), so using WCF would be an improvement in style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider providing these methods over WCF. That is the simplest way to achieve what you want.

See [A Simple Sample: WCF Service](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCF-Service-Create-Config.aspx)

Comment: +1 - you can knock up a simple WCF service (with no security and default settings) in next to no code, why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Never heard about WCF (I'm no professional). Would you be so kind and provide a Link to some introduction how to use WCF? I rushed over msdn and found a lot of stuff which looked like it was what i need. But all the code i found so far are just snippets. Could you point me to a complete democlass?

Comment: I found this to be quite a useful introduction: http://invalidcast.com/2010/04/a-gentle-introduction-to-wcf

Comment: Great introduction. Thanks, Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

You could also write your own TCP based server/client - it's quite simple to do in C#.

This makes for a reasonable exmple, then you can customize it to your needs:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server

Answer (score 0):

As note in the answer from Hasan WCF is the fastest and easiest protocol to implement.

If you want something lower level and parse bits and bytes yourself [`TcpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) is the way to go.

Comment: I tried TcpClient and it worked somehow. But I thought one shouldnt implement your own "protocoll" if there is any way to use already existing solutions.